# Expand EL-Context for some value

Tags: jsf, datatable, el

Example in xhtml works, because `#{row}` is defined in `p:dataTable`. If I call `getData` not in context of `p:dataTable` it returns  `null`. See `Values.iterateOverDatatableValues` for this situation where method returns `null`. How can I define `row` to use in my context. Possibly has datatable some functions to iterate over values so that `#{row}` will be defined?

Java:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
class Test {
  public Object getData () {
     return Faces.evaluateExpressionGet("#{row.someProperty}"); //The String "#{row.someProperty}" comes from a collection.
  }
}
```

XHTML `#{row}` is defined in `Test.getData()`:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{bean.values}" var="row">

   <p:column>
      <h:outputText value="#{test.data}" />
   </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Java, `#{row}` is undefined:

```
class Values {
  @Inject
  Test test;

  public void iterateOverDatatableValues (){
    DataTable dt = Components.findComponent("datatableId");
    for (Object o : dt.getValues()){
      test.getData(); // <---- NULL because #{row} is not defined. 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: _"Possibly has datatable some functions to iterate over values?"_ That is what it does in the showcase... What are you trying to achieve doing things in this sort of exotic way

Comment: I want to save EL-Expressions  like `#{row.data}` in some external table.

Comment: Next question: why?

Comment: Good question. I hope it is simple way to control datatable dynamicaly.

Comment: If you want exotic things, read about the 'binding' attribute in JSF... But it is rarely needed in modern times, so I think you are trying to achieve something in an unusual way and are running into an http://xyproblem.info

Comment: Thank you for your tip. Do you mean `binding` on `p:dataTable`? Do you know some links-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use expressionFactory().createValueExperssion method.

```
private void setRowEL(Object o) {
    ELContext elContext = Faces.getELContext();
    ExpressionFactory expressionFactory = Faces.getApplication().getExpressionFactory();
    ValueExpression aliasValueExpression = expressionFactory.createValueExpression(elContext, "#{row}", MyValue.class);
    aliasValueExpression.setValue(elContext, o);
}
```